Square root of t rule for non-normal returns
It is well known that the square root of t rule holds for log returns that are normally distributed.
However, does it also hold for non-normally distributed log returns?

In what context? E.g. that standard deviation grows as $\sqrt{t}$ does not require normality.

I edited my question. Is the scenario I am trying to describe clear?

By return, do you mean $\frac{P_t-P_{t-1}}{P_{t-1}}$? (Log-return would be $\ln(P_t)-\ln(P_{t-1}).$

Yes. That is what I mean by return.

And by continuous [return], do you mean continuously compounded [return], as in the interest being earned in continuous time rather than at discrete time points? Also, I am used to continuously compounded return but not continuous standard deviation.

By continuous I mean log returns.

I think that is a misnomer. Maybe editing your post to include some equations would help avoid confusion.

I was asking multiple things at once. I simplified the question and accepted your answer. Thank you.

If you are interested in discrete time, variance of a sum of mutually uncorrelated random variables equals the sum of their variances:
$$
\text{Var}(X_1 + \dots + X_T) = \text{Var}(X_1) + \dots + \text{Var}(X_T).
$$
If all the variances are the same,
$$
\text{Var}(X_1 + \dots + X_T) = T\sigma^2
$$
where $\sigma^2 := \text{Var}(X_1) = \dots = \text{Var}(X_T)$.
Standard deviation is the square root of variance. When all variances are the same, that makes
$$
\text{sd}(X_1 + \dots + X_T) = \sqrt{ \text{Var}(X_1 + \dots + X_T)} = \sqrt{T\sigma^2} = \sqrt{T}\sigma.
$$
This does not assume normality.
